# Titanium Appcelerator Android : WebView Html5 Local Audio / Video Not playing

Tags: android, webview, html5-audio, appcelerator-titanium

ERROR] : MediaResourceGetter: Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
[ERROR] : MediaPlayer: error (262, 0)

## [ERROR] : MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player

The audio / video file from external storage not playing under webview.

Comment: how are you set the path of your media

Comment: please refer the link >>>>

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5747